# IE Mode option limitations inside Edge Browser

Tags: security, internet-explorer

Microsoft has announced expiry of Internet Explorer & also provided replacement option as IE (Internet Explorer) mode inside Edge Browser for legacy applications.

However, I am exploring more information on below points-
***Whether IE Mode option is secure ?
What are the limitation or drawbacks of IE Mode option as compared to using Internet Explorer Desktop Browser (or other Browsers)?***

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Whether IE Mode option is secure?

IE mode is as secure as IE 11. It uses the Trident MSHTML engine from Internet Explorer 11.

> What are the limitation or drawbacks of IE Mode option as compared to using Internet Explorer Desktop Browser (or other Browsers)?

The limitation to use IE mode is that it doesn't support some functionality that IE desktop browser has. For a list of what is supported and what is not supported in IE mode, you can refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode#ie-mode-supports-the-following-internet-explorer-functionality).

When compared with Edge, of course **Edge is faster, more secure, and more modern**. For more information, you can refer to this blog: [The future of Internet Explorer on Windows 10 is in Microsoft Edge](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2021/05/19/the-future-of-internet-explorer-on-windows-10-is-in-microsoft-edge/).

Comment: Thank you @Yu . This is helpful for me. Also I came to know IE mode is dependent on Windows OS version. if any Windows OS support stop in future then we should get other version of OS who has IE mode in Edge browser.